# How to Restrict table value in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to limit user withdrawal which is from "users" table amount column if his "fund" table amount value is less than 0.001. i am trying to restrict it via withdraw controller but it is not working.
and withdraw is successfully submitted . but i want to restrict withdraw with this condition.
withdraw controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\AdminBalance;
use App\BasicSetting;
use App\GeneralSetting;
use App\ManualPayment;
use App\Plan;
use App\User;
use App\UserBalance;
use App\Withdraw;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class WithdrawController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function nomount(Request $request)
    {
        if (Fund::where('amount')!= 0 < 0.001) {
            session()->flash('message', 'Withdraw not Successfully Competed.');
            Session::flash('type', 'warnings');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong there. You may want to clean that up first.

Comment: ok please guide me

Comment: [Here, have some docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

```
$fund = Fund::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

if ($fund->amount < 0.0001) {
// not successful
}
```

Is this what you're trying to accomplish? If the current user signed in amount is less than 0.001 to not let them?

Or

```
if ( ($fund->amount - $request->withdraw_amount) < 0.001) {
// not successful 
}
```

If their fund amount and withdraw total is less than 0.001

Comment: ok. if  user details are not present in funds table. mean fund table is not populated with this user then

Comment: if ($fund) { // procced }  return back();

Comment: no i mean  if there is no data of this user in funds table. mean no record at all

Comment: the if statement would only execute if there is a value else it would jus return back. I don't get what you're trying to say